# Error type: <class 'requests.exceptions.SSLError'>

Tags: python-3.x, openssl, ssl-certificate, sslerrorhandler

I am getting `requests.exceptions.SSLError`

> Error: The app encountered an error processing your request.
> If you are an administrator of the app, view the full error in the logs. See aka.ms/appservice-logs for more information.
> Error type: <class 'requests.exceptions.SSLError'>

I tried by installing all the required libraries. How can I resolve this error?
python -m venv .venv
.venv\Scripts\activate
pip install -r requirements.in
python -m venv .venv
pip install -r requirements.in

Here is my error in logs
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='openaipublic.blob.core.windows.net', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /encodings/cl100k_base.tiktoken (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:992)')))

Call Stack:
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "D:\Project\azure-ai-search-demo\backend.venv\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 467, in _make_request     self._validate_conn(conn)   File "D:\Project\azure-ai-search-demo\backend.venv\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 1096, in _validate_conn     conn.connect()   File "D:\Project\azure-ai-search-demo\backend.venv\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 642, in connect     sock_and_verified = _ssl_wrap_socket_and_match_hostname(                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "D:\Project\azure-ai-search-demo\backend.venv\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 782, in *ssl_wrap_socket_and_match_hostname     ssl_sock = ssl_wrap_socket(                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "D:\Project\azure-ai-search-demo\backend.venv\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl*.py", line 470, in ssl_wrap_socket     ssl_sock = *ssl_wrap_socket_impl(sock, context, tls_in_tls, server_hostname)                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "D:\Project\azure-ai-search-demo\backend.venv\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl*.py", line 514, in _ssl_wrap_socket_impl     return ssl_context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\Python311\Lib\ssl.py", line 517, in wrap_socket     return self.sslsocket_class._create(            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\Python311\Lib\ssl.py", line 1075, in _create     self.do_handshake()   File "C:\Python311\Lib\ssl.py", line 1346, in do_handshake     self._sslobj.do_handshake() ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:992) During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred: Traceback (most recent call last):   File "D:\Project\azure-ai-search-demo\backend.venv\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 790, in urlopen     response = self.*make_request(                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "D:\Project\azure-ai-search-demo\backend.venv\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 491, in *make_request     raise new_e urllib3.exceptions.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (*ssl.c:992) The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception: Traceback (most recent call last):   File "D:\Project\azure-ai-search-demo\backend.venv\Lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 486, in send     resp = conn.urlopen(            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "D:\Project\azure-ai-search-demo\backend.venv\Lib\site-packages\opentelemetry\instrumentation\urllib3_*init**.py", line 228, in instrumented_urlopen     return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "D:\Project\azure-ai-search-demo\backend.venv\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 844, in urlopen     retries = retries.increment(               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "D:\Project\azure-ai-search-demo\backend.venv\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 515, in increment     raise MaxRetryError(*pool, url, reason) from reason  # type: ignore[arg-type]     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='openaipublic.blob.core.windows.net', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /encodings/cl100k_base.tiktoken (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (*ssl.c:992)'))) During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred: Traceback (most recent call last):   File "D:\Project\azure-ai-search-demo\backend.venv\Lib\site-packages\opentelemetry\trace_*init**.py", line 573, in use_span     yield span   File "D:\Project\azure-ai-search-demo\backend.venv\Lib\site-packages\opentelemetry\sdk\trace_*init**.py", line 1046, in start_as_current_span     yield span_context   File "D:\Project\azure-ai-search-demo\backend.venv\Lib\site-packages\opentelemetry\instrumentation\requests_*init**.py", line 309, in instrumented_send     raise exception.with_traceback(exception.**traceback**)   File "D:\Project\azure-ai-search-demo\backend.venv\Lib\site-packages\opentelemetry\instrumentation\requests_*init**.py", line 230, in instrumented_send     result = wrapped_send(self, request, **kwargs)  # *** PROCEED              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "D:\Project\azure-ai-search-demo\backend.venv\Lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 703, in send     r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "D:\Project\azure-ai-search-demo\backend.venv\Lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 517, in send     raise SSLError(e, request=request) requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='openaipublic.blob.core.windows.net', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /encodings/cl100k_base.tiktoken (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:992)')))

I have Chat Ai with python as backend, I want to chat with Ai, in response it is showing error
Error: The app encountered an error processing your request.
If you are an administrator of the app, view the full error in the logs. See aka.ms/appservice-logs for more information.
Error type: <class 'requests.exceptions.SSLError'>